# How to restrict processing to specified number of cores in spark standalone

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We have tried using various combinations of settings - but mpstat is showing that all or most cpu's are always being used (on a single 8 core system)

Following have been tried:

set master to:

```
local[2]
```

send in

```
conf.set("spark.cores.max","2")
```

in the spark configuration

Also using

```
--total-executor-cores 2
```

and

```
--executor-cores 2
```

In all cases

```
mpstat -A
```

shows that all of the CPU's are being used - and not just by the master.

So I am at a loss presently.  We do need to limit the usage to a specified number of cpu's.

Comment: What is it showing on spark UI??

Comment: @sb'  The spark UI is not presently available: the sys admin is working on that. I will get back here next week when it is ready.

Comment: The spark gui shows the correct number of cores. The setting is not working however: all cores are being utilized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently spark `standalone` *ignores* the `spark.cores.max` setting. That setting *does* work in yarn.

Comment: then how do you accomplish this in standalone?

Comment: it is not possible.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with memory size and I wanted to increase it but none of the above worked for me as well. Based on [this user post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31058669/2827771) I was able to resolve my problem and I think this should also work for number of cores:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

# In Jupyter you have to stop the current context first
sc.stop()

# Create new config
conf = (SparkConf().set("spark.cores.max", "2"))

# Create new context
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Hope this helps you. And please, if you have resolved your problem, send your solution as answer for this post so we can all benefit from it :)

Cheers

Comment: +1 for spark.cores.max - fyi, if using spark-submit you should be able to specify from the command line using: --conf spark.cores.max=2

Comment: as shown in the original post those were not having any effect in `standalone` mode. I think you are not running in standalone. This does not answer the original question and in fact duplicates information already contained there.

Comment: @javadba It is not an answer but could be added as an update to your question or posted as a comment.

Comment: This was in the original question `conf.set("spark.cores.max","2")`  . In addition you don't downvote another answer for a reason of "my answer was downvoted".

Comment: This was not my intention whatsoever and have already flagged it as not an answer. If you think my answer is not acceptable and does not provide any useful information, you are more than welcome to do so as well. After all, as I have mentioned it helped me with other configurations and that's why it was posted here. Good luck