# Scala: How to get a range of rows in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` created by running `sqlContext.read` of a Parquet file.

The `DataFrame` consists of 300 M rows. I need to use these rows as input to another function, but I want to do it in smaller batches to prevent OOM error.

Currently, I am using `df.head(1000000)` to read the first 1M rows, but I cannot find a way to read the subsequent rows. I tried `df.collect()`, but it gives me a Java OOM error.

I want to iterate over this dataframe. I tried adding another column with the withColumn() API to generate a unique set of values to iterate over, but none of the existing columns in the dataframe have solely unique values.

For example, I tried val `df = df1.withColumn("newColumn", df1("col") + 1)` as well as `val df = df1.withColumn("newColumn",lit(i+=1))`, both of which do not return a sequential set of values.

Any other way to get the first n rows of a dataframe and then the next n rows, something that works like a range function of `SqlContext`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simple use the limit and except api of dataset or dataframes as follows

```
long count = df.count();
int limit = 50;
while(count > 0){
    df1 = df.limit(limit);
    df1.show();            //will print 50, next 50, etc rows
    df = df.except(df1);
    count = count - limit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Made small changes to get this to work: 
var count:long = df.count();  
val limit:Int = 50;    
while(count > 0){   
    df1 = df.limit(limit);  
    df1.show();            //will print 50, next 50, etc rows
    df = df.except(df1);
    count = count - limit;
}

Comment: No, it will not if you want to remove duplicate rows you just create new dataframe by using distinct on the current dataframe