# AWS Glue job is failing for large input csv data on s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

For small s3 input files (~10GB), glue ETL job works fine but for the larger dataset (~200GB), the job is failing.

Adding a part of ETL code.

```
# Converting Dynamic frame to dataframe
df = dropnullfields3.toDF()

# create new partition column
partitioned_dataframe = df.withColumn('part_date', df['timestamp_utc'].cast('date'))

# store the data in parquet format on s3 
partitioned_dataframe.write.partitionBy(['part_date']).format("parquet").save(output_lg_partitioned_dir, mode="append")
```

Job executed for 4 hours and threw error.

> File "script_2017-11-23-15-07-32.py", line 49, in 
>   partitioned_dataframe.write.partitionBy(['part_date']).format("parquet").save(output_lg_partitioned_dir,
>   mode="append") File
>   "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1511449472652_0001/container_1511449472652_0001_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py",
>   line 550, in save File
>   "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1511449472652_0001/container_1511449472652_0001_02_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1133, in **call** File
>   "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1511449472652_0001/container_1511449472652_0001_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
>   line 63, in deco File
>   "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1511449472652_0001/container_1511449472652_0001_02_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 319, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling o172.save. : org.apache.spark.SparkException:
>   Job aborted. at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:147)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:101)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:87)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:87)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:492)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:198)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244) at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357) at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280) at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>   at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214) at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Total size of serialized results of 3385 tasks (1024.1 MB) is bigger
>   than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB) at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>   at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>   at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257) at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48) at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918) at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931) at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951) at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:127)
>   ... 30 more
>
> End of LogType:stdout

I would appreciate it if you could provide any guidance to resolve this issue.

Comment: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 3385 tasks (1024.1 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB). Don't know how to resolve this issue. please help!

Comment: I also tried this solution but got the same issue.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/31058669/3957916

Comment: This https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12837 might be related

Answer (score 2):

You can only set configurable options like `maxResultSize` during context instantiation, and glue provides you with a context (from memory you can't instantiate a new context). I don't think you will be able to change the value of this property.

You'll normally get this error if you collect results to the driver which exceed the specified size. You aren't doing that in this case so the error is confusing.

It seems like you are spawning 3385 tasks, which are presumably related to the dates in your input file (3385 dates, ~9 years?). You might try writing this file in batches, e.g.

```
partitioned_dataframe = df.withColumn('part_date', df['timestamp_utc'].cast('date'))
for year in range(2000,2018):
    partitioned_dataframe = partitioned_dateframe.where(year(part_date) = year)
    partitioned_dataframe.write.partitionBy(['part_date'])
        .format("parquet")
        .save(output_lg_partitioned_dir, mode="append")
```

I haven't checked this code; you'll at least need to import `pyspark.sql.functions.year` for it to work.

When I've done data processing with Glue I simply found that batching the work was more effective than trying to get large datasets be completed successfully. The system is good but hard to debug; the stability on large data doesn't come easily.